# how i do the calculation for table that has been created in model page

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function fetch_item($item)
{
   $this->db->where("pgroup",$item);
   $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('itemmaster');
   $this->db- 
 >join('pgroup','pgroup.pgroupid 
     = itemmaster.catcode','left 
 outer');
     $query_result = $this->db->get()- 
    >result();

        //pass query result as html

        $output = '<table class="table 
      table- 
     striped table-bordered table- 
        hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
           <th>Qty</th>
        <th>amount</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
  <tbody>';

      if($query_result !='false'){

       foreach ($query_result as $key 
         => 
         $value) {

       $output .='<tr>
          <td>'.$value- 
             >product_name.'</td>
         <td><input style="width:100px"  
         name="rate" type="text" 
    class="form- 
     control input-xs"   value=""></td>
     <td><input style="width:100px"  
      name="qty" type="text" 
       class="form- 
       control input-xs"    value=""> 
    </td>
      <td><input style="width:100px"  
         name="amount" type="text" 
        class="form- 
       control input-xs"    value=""> 
        </td>
      </tr>';
       }
}

       $output .="</tbody>
  </table>";

 echo $output;

  }
```

this is model code for fetching data and 
 created in table format..

my problm is how i done the calculation 
like qty * value and display in value text 
 box.in model code i have created table in that table how do this calcuations.......
how i do the calculation for table that has been created in model page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update you foreach loop code from below code

```
$i=0;
foreach ($query_result as $key => $value) {

    $output .='<tr>
          <td>'.$value->product_name.'</td>
         <td><input style="width:100px" name="rate" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="" id="rate_'.$i.'" onchange="calculate('.$i.')"></td>
         <td><input style="width:100px" name="qty" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="" id="qty_'.$i.'" onchange="calculate('.$i.')"> </td>
         <td><input style="width:100px" name="amount" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="" id="amount_'.$i.'"> 
         </td></tr>';
   $i++;
}
```

add below code into your view page make sure jquery min lode before this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculate(id){
    var rate=$("#rate_"+id).val();
    var qty=$("#qty_"+id).val();
    if(qty=="")
        qty=0;
    if(rate=="")
        rate=0;
    var total=rate*qty;
    $("#amount_"+id).val(total);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: sir i have gave qty and rate dynamically

Comment: you need javasript or jquery call onblure qty input and then calculate total

Comment: that is my prblm sir how i wrote in view page.. because this table had been created in model page(that is fetching data from database and view in table format)

Comment: Okay i'll give you code. you want update total amount when user add qty and rate of that product right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182836/discussion-between-esakkichandra-and-sachin).